# Catching server exception in selenium?

Tags: c#, testing, selenium, automated-tests

I'm new to selenium and wonder if it's possible to catch internal server errors? For many cases in my tests it only stops if it can't find certain tags and such. Maybe you could check the response all the time and identify if it's an error from the server? Am I using it wrong? It must be a better way to go.
I've spent two hours googling this. :(

I'm using IIS for my server if it helps, programming with selenium in C#.

Thanks!

Comment: You will have to push that information to Selenium. It has no knowledge of the back end of your application, so you will need to tell it. One way would be to have your application stuff out the error logs to the console & have it scan the console logs (which Selenium *does* have access to). Another way is to take this out of Selenium's hands and have a separate tool (i.e a CI tool) to do this for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Am I using it wrong?

IMHO - yes. Propagating

> internal server errors

is wrong by design and even dangerous. All that must be exposed into the UI is a friendly message informing that something went wrong.

Still there is a way of checking your server errors. The Selenium team recommends such [Database Validation](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/06_test_design_considerations.jsp) approach that can solve your case.

Comment: Thank you for confirming that! But why would it be dangerous? Just curious.

Comment: Exposing internal errors and especially errors stack traces can be exploited by malicious users.